# How can I insert position id in this binary referral system

Tags: laravel

[User table with position (Right,Left)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgqYO.png)

I created user register system with referral link.
New user can register under this referral id easily and I set new user into right and left position.
But I still need important point is to add position id in user table because of binary tree system ,new users will place in right and left tree.
So if exsiting user has infront of him,the place will be below of exsiting users.
For this I want to set position id to count and order this binary tree users.

here my registercontroller

```
  protected function create(array $data)
{
  $referred_by = Cookie::get('referral');
     return  $user =  User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
       'position' => $data['position'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'affiliate_id' => str_random(10),
        'referred_by'   => $referred_by,
        //'position_id' => ?


    ]);

}
```

here my user table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('position');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
      //  $table->string('posid');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}



Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
 $table->increments('id');
 $table->unsignedInteger('parent_id')->nullable(); // root user will have null parent_id
 $table->string('name');
 $table->string('position');
 $table->string('email')->unique();
 $table->string('password');
 $table->string('posid');
 $table->rememberToken();
 $table->timestamps();

 $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade'); // cascade delete children when deleting parent
```

});

How can I edit registercontroller to get this position id in database.
Can I use parent_id for every user id who register in system.
How can use it.

Please help me.

Comment: You need `parent_id` for certain. When you register user to be someone's children you must know user who is going to get new children and consequently you would know `parent_id`. Querying that parent you have three possible options: 1.) both places free (left and right) so you can allow user to choose which side to pick; 2.) one side would be occupied so you would have just one option left whichever it was; 3.) both legs would be already occupied which stops further process in that kind of binary system.

Comment: So first query and get user that is referring one and check if that one already has two referred children to know should you continue or stop process.

Comment: Hello Tpojka ,your suggestion is good ,Yes I need parent_id for that childrens,Can I use parent_id in user table as I edited above question Please check it and How can ue parent_id as position_id call in registercontroller bro.?

Comment: Try with : `public function children(){return $this->hasMany( 'App\User', 'parent_id', 'id' );}` 
and 
`public function parent(){return $this->hasOne( 'App\User', 'id', 'parent_id' );}`

Comment: Plz help this problem bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51472222/how-can-i-use-this-variable-to-get-correct-count-in-this-binary-plan-registerati